# Stop recording when there is no audio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm working on a voice recording program using Naudio Library.
Right now to record I have to press on record button and than the save button.
I want to make the program recording all the time and save the recorded audio automatically.
Thanks for helping. 
here's some of the code. 
start recording:

```
    NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;
    NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveWriter = null;

    private void SRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav;";
            string wavoutputpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            wavoutputpath += "\\Speech.wav";
            save.FileName = wavoutputpath;

            int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

            sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
            sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
            sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

            sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
            waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(save.FileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);

            sourceStream.StartRecording();
    }

    private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveWriter == null) return;

        waveWriter.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        waveWriter.Flush();
    }
```

stop recording:

```
        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.StopRecording();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }
        if (waveWriter != null)
        {
            waveWriter.Dispose();
            waveWriter = null;
        }
```

Comment: What is it you want to do. Record all the time, or stop when there is no audio?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As this question stands, it is difficult to help you.  Please post the code that you have so far and a solution will be much easier to create.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do it stop the recording when there is no audio, you can check if a certain number of 'silent' samples has passed. In the `WaveIn.DataAvailable` event handler, you can examine each sample by looking at the bytes in `e.Buffer`. Say you are recording in `16 bit`, every `2 bytes` forms one sample. You can convert it to an `Int16` to examine it. Also for starting recording when audio is available again, you can examine the sample value and if it exceeds a threshold value, you can start writing it.

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

@Jester has a good answer, just no code to help others out that have no idea on how to implement this.

Audio is not my area of expertise, however, here is what I came up with:

```
int threshold = <SETYOURTHRESHOLD>;
int value = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, (e.BytesRecorded - 2)));
if (value < threshold)
    sourceStream.StopRecording();
```

all in the:

```
public void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
```

Method.

Of course this is only a start and more work is required to turn this into a fine running machine!